# How to set the static series name to the element result based on the categories in the HighChart

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I have question regarding series name, How can i set static series name to the element based on the categories in the HighChart.

**The expected output will be like this:**

[image: Output]
[image: Output]

**As of now I have result on my web app.**

[image: My Output]

Is it possible to change that Series1,Series2,Series3 based on what I want to put on the Series name?

**I have here my codes:**

```
categories = [],
series = [];

$.getJSON('ajax/ams_sla_report_chart.php', function(data,name){


    data.forEach(function(arr) {
        arr.forEach(function(el, i) {

            if (i === 0) {
                categories.push(el);

            } else if (series[i - 1]) {
                series[i - 1].data.push(el);

            } else {

                series.push({
                    name:['MR','MR_HIT','MR_HIT_PERCENTAGE'],       
                    data: [el]

                });


            }
        });
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containers',
            type: 'column',
            inverted: false    
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
          },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        title: {
           text: 'Priority Based on SLA'
        },

        series:series

    });


    function showValues() {
    $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
    $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
    $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
    }

    // Activate the sliders
    $('#sliders_eng input').on('input change', function () {
        chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = parseFloat(this.value);
        showValues();
        chart.redraw(false);
    });

    showValues();


});
```

Comment: Hi @DevGe, So would you like to have only one series for one category? Shole the result be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xh6ak7ts/, but without a `stacking`?

Comment: @ppotaczek yes each category has different naming in the value..

Comment: @ppotaczek like what I share on the top of my question..

Comment: Example, This series1 = 'New series1'

Comment: @ppotaczek as you can see bro, why is it happen the names, duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the series names array outside of the loop and use only one name in the loop:

```
var seriesNames = ['MR', 'MR_HIT', 'MR_HIT_PERCENTAGE'],
...
data.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            categories.push(el);
        } else if (series[i - 1]) {
            series[i - 1].data.push(el)
        } else {
            series.push({
                name: seriesNames[i - 1],
                data: [el]
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ewauprqh/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek for helping me now solved my problem thanks alot